Vidiot Video Editor-Error
I downloaded Vidiot Video editor from the app store in the newest Ubuntu OS which i installed myself on an older laptop and I can not get it to open it gives me this error.
11:12:32: Directory '/home/david/.vidiot' couldn't be created (error 13: Permission denied)
